# Is a sleep in the main thread of a windows process always a bad thing

Tags: debugging, winapi, unity-game-engine

I'm investigating an issue where a (Unity-based) application hangs with an *AppHangB1* event after several hours of runtime, and needs to be killed manually. Unfortunately, this application is supposed to run for over 12 hours, continuously, in an unattended setup.

We have managed to create a .dmp file from it's "hanging" state using DebugDiag, and are now trying to make sense of the contents. The first thing that jumps out to me is this:

[image: Main thread sleeping]

Looks to me like the main thread is **sleeping**. Something a main thread is never supposed to do in my book, because it will prevent the app from responding to windows messages. I am assuming this could be the direct cause of the AppHangB1.

**If someone could confirm whether this assumption is generally correct, and if not, why, that would be great!**

Extra info: memory usage and handle count of the process are stable. General and specific pointers on how to tackle this particular issue are of course welcome, but to keep the question ontopic I'd just like to focus on the sleep in the main thread we are seeing here.

Comment: I would capture it happening with the unity profiler instead of just a stack trace to see how much time is actually being spent there.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks! The problem only occurs in non-development builds of the player, so I don't think the Unity profiler can help us out. Have you had any success using the profiler when the issue is not in the scripting (in this particular case, we suspect the video plugin and/or one of the codecs it uses)?

Comment: Yes, I have not had to deal with a plugin but I have used it to track down a fps issue and found it was the time spent on the geometry instead of the scripting like we thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to leave this question in limbo, so here is my take. If any other answers come along from more knowledgable people I'll glady mark those in stead.

- **No, a sleep on the main thread is not necessarily a bad thing**. The time limit for Windows "Application Hung" detection is 5 seconds, there is lots of code that does tiny sleeps for various reasons. One of those is a 0-millisecond sleep that just relinquishes the time slice.
- *However*, it can be a strong indicator of a problem if multiple AppHang crash dumps show the main thread in the exact same sleeping state.

In this particular case, the dumps always showed a sleep inside *msmpeg2vdec.dll*, the Windows MPEG2 video codec as used by the popular AVPro plugin we use for video playback. We switched video formats for all the videos, **and now the application no longer hangs**.